# Count clickers for each element of list Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have button for each element of list.

```
 <li *ngFor= "let sth of sthList">
     <button [ngClass]="'button'" (click)="plus()">plus</button>;
    {{count}}
 </li>
```

I would like to count clicks for each button. When I do this:

```
count: number = 0;
plus() {
    this.count++;
  }
```

buttons dont work separately. Do you knw how to write function which will work independently on each one button?

Comment: You want a separet count for each rate. So the count should be a property of rate. And the plus() method should increment the count of a given rate: `plus(rate)`, `rate.count++`.

Comment: Ofc you cant do that with that snippet, you have one property for all the elements in the list. You should try to either extend the objects in the list with an extra property or add a different object that maps a list element to its click counter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a count for each rate object and increase the count on the property.

something like this,

```
<li *ngFor= "let rate of rateList">
     <button [ngClass]="'button1'" (click)="plus(rate)">+</button>;
    {{rate.count}}
 </li>
```

and in TS

```
plus(rate:any) {
    rate.count += 1;
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdjkxu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**